# Icon appears on top of Email signature

Tags: html-email

I created an email signature which was working fine until August 14th when the last test was done. But today, on Outlook, the signature has this icon on top of it and it doesn't happen to everyone. The icon [image] has the title `Show original size`. Nothing has changed for the HTML from where the signature is copied.

Here is the signature http://joseadrian.com/signature.html. It happens only with the visual version, not the text one on the textarea. And again, when I send it, it doesn't happen but it does when other users do it using the same email client.

While checking the `message source` it appears that Outlook filters the email for some people and adds the images behind a proxy `//imgproxy-prod.services.web.outlook.com/proxy/?u=...`. That's the only difference I could detect.

- I send the email with the signature, the other user doesn't see the icon
- Other user sends email to me with the signature, I see the icon
- Other user sends email to another user wit the signature, they see the icon

Is there any way for that icon to not appear? The icon does not appear on the `message source`, it appears after one second after the email is loaded. The email clients used are Outlook for Web and for desktop (app/program)

Answer (score 0):

After analyzing different emails, the icon appears when an element's width within the email is greater than the reading panel.

And somehow the email client for them is setting a fixed width to the table when the width on the HTML is '100%'.

```html
<!-- Somehow  vvvvvvvvvv  turns into a fixed width `##px` in the email client -->
<table style="width:100%" width="100%">
```